# How to include Variables file that is part of an installed pip package

Tags: python, pip, robotframework

I'm currently having trouble including a Robot Framework "Variables" file that is contained within a python pip package. I can successfully include files in this package as a "Library", but not "Variables". The reason I have variables stored in a pip package is that this package is privately maintained and is used across a variety of projects.

Example contents of the file with both variables and functions that I need to access from Robot Framework:
"package_file.py"

```
VARIABLE_ABC = "important constant here"


def my_function(arg1, arg2)
    return 0
```

I can create a dummy file that merely imports all the variables from the package file and its path is known and consistent. I would consider this to be a workaround and not the ideal solution:

"my_variables_file_copy.py"

```
from my_module.package_file import *
```

See the example syntax from one of my .robot files below for a better explanation of what is going on:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Description of this file

# This brings in functions, but not variables
Library          my_module.package_file

# This doesn't work
Variables        my_module.package_file

# This does work, but is not ideal
Variables        my_variables_file_copy.py

# This would also work but is not ideal and could be change depending on the installation
Variables         path/to/installed/pip/package/my_module/package_file.py
```

Any advice on how to handle this situation?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that importing "brings in functions, but not variables"? An import *runs* the file being imported. If there are variables defined in that file at the top-level scope, then they'll be accessible via `imported_file_name.top_level_variable_name` which is best practice, as it clearly shows the namespace to which that variable belongs. Can you provide an example of a file whose variables you want to access and how you're trying to access them?

Comment: Is it not enough to add  ```PYTHONPATH:  - variables``` in the robot.yaml file? I haven't worked that much directly with Robotframework, but that might indicate where to look for variables (tho, you would need to create a variables folder). Then I would only write ```Variables          my_module.py```  to import them. At least that way works with Robocorp software, which uses Robotframework

Comment: @ddejohn I edited the original post to better provide the additional info you asked for.

While I agree with you about variable scope best practices, as far as I know, I cannot get the Robot Framework syntax correct to access a variable through a module. This does not work:

`Some Keyword    ${my_module.package_file.VARIABLE_ABC}`

Anytime other variables files are included, they are accessed simply by their name. Keywords (aka functions) that are included via the "Library" call at the top of a file can be accessed by just calling `Function Name` or with the module prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for this has recently been added in Robot Framework 5.0

https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-5.0.rst#variable-files-can-be-imported-as-modules

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).